# Rewrite URL to all lower case letters and redirect some URL to home page using .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My problem is I want to write my own rule for `.htaccess` file. I have searched the internet, they didn't told me how to write my own specific rule. All I know is that it uses regular expressions. I have little knowledge of regex.

What I am looking for is I have the following links

```
http://example.com/work/project-1 
http://example.com/work/project-2
```

when user enter like this

```
http://example.com/work/PrOJect-2
```

I want them to redirect to (converting all caps to small)

```
http://example.com/work/project-2
```

But when user enter like this

```
http://example.com/work/
```

or

```
http://example.com/work
```

I want to redirect to home page.

For doing so I have htaccess file 
which have some rules like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^work(.*)/([^/]*) work-single.php$1?slug=$2 [QSA]
```

Please help me to write these rules.

Comment: I am not familiar with editing .htaccess but it seems you want to redirect based on the url you enter - have a look at http://yourls.org/ this is a link shortening site written in php that looks at the url entered compares with a mysql database and redirects - it may give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

**What you are trying to achieve is called URL rewriting.**

Here's an example of a working .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url_params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The result of using the above rules set is that the full URL from the request is being passed on the server-side to index.php, where the string can be fetched using:

```
$urlString = $_GET['url_params'];
```

and further processed, for an example slicing the string into an array of tokens:

```
$urlTokens = explode('/', $urlString);

foreach($urlTokens as $token){

    // do something with each token

}
```

and finally analyse the tokens (a task that most people these days dont actually manually do becuase of the use of frameworks that take care of this automatically. e.g. Zend framework), for each valid "token" you take the appropriate action (in modern frameworks this is called "Routing").

For a complete tutorial on how to setup url rewriting, you can check:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

It can be pretty straight forward, or completely complicated - depends on your needs.

Bear in mind that this is only an example and might not work for your exact situation, you might want to customise it to fit your needs - or at least learn from it and solve your problem.

I would recommend that you read and learn more about the subject, it will make it easier for you to use the technique.

Hope it helps a bit